# Parse DateTime string into Noda Time LocalDateTime in a forgiving way?

Tags: parsing, datetime, nodatime

I have GetDateTimeOffset(string latitude, string longitude, string dateTime) web service which determines Time Offset given Lat/Long and local DateTime.

Our current client web page uses DateTimePicker plugin http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/. We use the default date formatting and format time part as 'h:mm:ss TT Z' so a string we pass to a server looks like '01/22/2014 12:09:00 AM -05:00'. But I'm thinking about making our web service more generic, so it should be forgiving for a format of dateTime string passed in.

Right now I'm parsing DateTime string (user input) in an sub-optimal way using BCL http://goo.gl/s9Kypx.

```
var tmpDateTime = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now).DateTime;
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(dateTime))
{
    try
    {
        // Note: Looks stupid? I need to throw away TimeZone Offset specified in dateTime string (if any).
        // Funny thing is that calling DateTime.Parse(dateTime) would automatically modify DateTime for its value in a system timezone.
        tmpDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Parse(dateTime).DateTime;
    }

    catch (Exception) { }
}
```

Questions:

- a) Is the above code a proper BCL method of parsing user input into DateTime in flexible "forgiving" way?
- b) What would be a good and "forgiving" way of parsing dateTime string into LocalDateTime (Noda Time class)?

I suppose I should use

- http://goo.gl/a2wYco for getting the system's LocalDateTime in Noda Time
- LocalDateTimePattern.Parse(String) and probably the approach described by Jon Skeet here http://goo.gl/F8k51c for ability to parse various formats. But **which patterns to use** to make it really flexible?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to parse that specific pattern, then you can do that `DateTimeOffset.TryParseExact`, or with NodaTime code to parse from that input:

```cs
var defaultValue = new OffsetDateTime(new LocalDateTime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0), Offset.Zero);
var pattern = OffsetDateTimePattern.Create("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt o<m>", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, defaultValue);
var result = pattern.Parse("01/22/2014 12:09:00 AM -05:00");
if (!result.Success)
{
    // handle your error
}

OffsetDateTime value = result.Value;
LocalDateTime local = value.LocalDateTime;
```

But going back to your statement:

> But I'm thinking about making our web service more generic, so it should be forgiving for a format of dateTime string passed in.

That is not a good idea.  If you are creating a *web service*, you should be very explicit about the format that you are using.  Preferably, it should not be this format that you showed here, but instead should be the ISO-8601 extended format such as `2014-01-22T12:09:00-05:00`

Comment: Matt, how to specify ISO-8601 extended format as a first parameter of OffsetDateTimePattern.Create()? Does Noda Time provide some literal constant for that format? Othervise, what format string should I pass to parse "2014-01-22T12:09:00-05:00" string?

Comment: What is a meaning of o<m> ?

Comment: You'll find that `OffsetDateTimePattern.ExtendedIsoPattern` already exists, though you could wire it up manually using the General pattern (`G`)

Comment: `o<m>` is an offset pattern.  Specifically, it's the "Medium format standard pattern".  See [OffsetDateTime Patterns](http://nodatime.org/1.2.x/userguide/offsetdatetime-patterns.html) and  [Offset Patterns](http://nodatime.org/1.2.x/userguide/offset-patterns.html).

Comment: Thanks again, Matt. I understood and agreed with what you said above -  web service should require a specific format of DateTime provided by clients. I reworked my web service to accept only two ISO-8601 formats: one with and another without time offset part. (Two - to make client programmer's life a bit easier).

I also replaced BCL method calls with Noda Time. Once I feel satisfied with it I'll add my code as a comment of the first post at http://goo.gl/s9Kypx

Comment: Hi Matt. Could you explain to me the significance in `(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0)` as opposed to `1970, 1, 1, 0, 0`? Epoch time vs what you specified.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage - Good question!  See my response [in your other post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22390334/634824).