# Converting NodaTime to Unix timestamp and the importance of LocalDateTime

Tags: c#, nodatime

I am currently using NodaTime based on my frustrations dealing with timezones in C#'s `DateTime` class. So far, I'm really pleased.

```
public static string nodaTimeTest(string input)
{
    var defaultValue = new OffsetDateTime(new LocalDateTime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0), Offset.Zero);
    var pattern = OffsetDateTimePattern.Create("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sso<m>", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, defaultValue);
    var result = pattern.Parse(input).Value;

    return result.ToString();
}
```

I have three specific questions. Above is the method I use where I parse in dateTime strings. I have a `format` string which allows me how to parse the input. My questions are:

---

Does it matter what my `LocalDateTime(..)` is? The method I used is Matt Johnson's Stack [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21300317/1913389), and his came with the date `2000, 1, 1, 0, 0`. I thought that was odd, since most date classes I know use the Epoch time `1970, 1, 1, 0 ,0`, so I changed my method to contain the Epoch date, but the outputs were the same:

[image]

---

How do I convert the time to a Unix timestamp? It does not appear there's a built-in method to do so.

---

Using this method:

```
public static string nodaTimeTest6(string input, int timeZone)
{
    // var defaultValue = new OffsetDateTime(new LocalDateTime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0), Offset.Zero);
    var defaultValue = new OffsetDateTime(new LocalDateTime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0), Offset.FromHours(timeZone));
    var pattern = OffsetDateTimePattern.Create("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sso<m>", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, defaultValue);
    var result = pattern.Parse(input);

    return result.Value.ToString();
}
```

I'm testing out the abilities of NodaTime with this method -- specifically, I was wondering if I can parse in a date/time that HAS offset defined inside, and at the same time, my `timeZone` input also allows input of timezones/offsets. Interestingly enough, my input `timeZone` gets ignored, so the offset in my output of `nodaTimeTest6` is the input date string:

[image]

Is this desired behavior?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Does it matter what my LocalDateTime(..) is?

- The `OffsetDateTimePattern.Create` method requires a default value. It's only used if the parsing were to fail and you didn't check `result.Success` before using `result.Value`.
- The other patterns have an overload that doesn't require a default value (see [issue #267](https://code.google.com/p/noda-time/issues/detail?id=267)). I chose the particular default value of `2000-01-01T00:00:00.0000000+00:00` because it's similar to what [the other patterns use](https://code.google.com/p/noda-time/source/browse/src/NodaTime/Text/LocalDateTimePattern.cs#25) when you don't specify a default explicitly.
- There really isn't any significance though. You can use any default you wish.

> How do I convert the time to a Unix timestamp? It does not appear there's a built-in method to do so.

- The `result.Value` is an `OffsetDateTime`.  The `Instant` type uses the Unix epoch, so you can do this:

  ```
  int unixTime = result.Value.ToInstant().Ticks / NodaConstants.TicksPerSecond;
  ```
- Note that Unix timestamps are precise to the nearest second.  If you're passing to JavaScript, you'd want to use `TicksPerMillisecond` and return it in a `long`.

> ... I was wondering if I can parse in a date/time that HAS offset defined inside, and at the same time, my `timeZone` input also allows input of timezones/offsets.

- Sorry, but I don't fully understand what you're asking here.  Can you please clarify?
- From the code you provided, it looks like you are confusing the offset for the default value with the offset for the input string.  The default value is only used if parsing *fails*.
- If you want to control the offset instead of including it in the input, then use a `LocalDateTimePattern` instead of an `OffsetDateTimePattern` to do the parsing.  After it's parsed, you can associated it with a particular zone.
- Also, watch your naming conventions.  `int timeZone` doesn't make sense (that's an offset, not a time zone).  Perhaps `int offsetHours`, or better yet, `Offset timeZoneOffset`.

Comment: 1. Hm, if it doesn't matter, then I'll just use whatever works then! 2. Thanks! Will try this. 3. I honestly don't know/understand the difference between offset/timezone; always thought they meant the same thing.

Comment: Have a look at [the timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).   Specifically the section "Time Zone != Offset".  You might also want to read [the DST tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/dst/info), which is related.

Comment: Very much thanks Matt. The Unix time converter worked perfectly. Do you have a method that does the exact reverse of the unix time? Input is unix time and it comes out as a date time.

Comment: That's built in with `Instant.FromSecondsSinceUnixEpoch` or `Instant.FromMillisecondsSinceUnixEpoch`.